# AFNetworking: `setImageWithURLRequest:request` method didn't use cached image(disk cache) when the app is reopened

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, afnetworking

First time to use `AFNetworking`. When I use it to download/reload image for my collectionView with `setImageWithURLRequest:request` method, I found the images could be downloaded, but never load from the cached image.

Well, I searched internet before asking this question, most of them said to use `setImageWithURLRequest:request` and it has a cache policy for the NSURLRequest I could configure before. I configure the policy as `NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad`, it means use the cached data first otherwise re-download it if I understand correctly. And they also said I could check the `response == nil` to know if cached image is used. I also set the cache capacity in AppDelegate `didFinishLaunching`, though my image is roughly 50KB.

However it never happened, the `response` is always has a value in my case. Please advice what I am missing here?

**AppDelegate**

```
    NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:20 * 1024 * 1024
                                                            diskCapacity:200 * 1024 * 1024
                                                            directoryURL:nil];
    [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];
```

**The code snipper for download image**

```
- (void)setupThumbnailImage {
    
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:weakSelf.video.thumbnailImageName];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval:60];
        [weakSelf.videoImageView setImageWithURLRequest:request placeholderImage:nil success:^(NSURLRequest * _Nonnull request, NSHTTPURLResponse * _Nullable response, UIImage * _Nonnull image) {
            
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                if (!response) {
                    weakSelf.videoImageView.image = image;
                    NSLog(@"use cache image ");
                } else {
                    weakSelf.videoImageView.image = image;
                    NSLog(@"redownload image ");
                }
            });
        } failure:^(NSURLRequest * _Nonnull request, NSHTTPURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
        }];
    });
}
```

#### Update

Per Larme's comment, I did 2 test. First I put a break point on line 97    `UIImage *cachedImage = [imageCache imageforRequest:urlRequest withAdditionalIdentifier:nil];` in file "UIImageView+AFNetworking.h".

1. Use `NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataDontLoad` and turn off network(offline mode).

Result: In debug console, I could see the `cachedImage` is nil. Then it try to use network to download the image. And an error fired as no network available.

> Task <8A1D55F5-F884-4FEC-B7DF-756BD0BB2B34>.<6> HTTP load failed, 0/0
> bytes (error code: -1009 [1:50]) Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain
> Code=-1009 "The Internet connection appears to be offline."

2. use `NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad`, and put my method for downloading image into `viewDidAppear`, then do a VC switch/switch back.

Result: this method fired again, and this time it used cache image because code step over into `if (cachedImage)` statement and also  `NSLog(@"use cache image ");` is printed out.

So in-memory cache image works. Current problem is in-disk cache image, when the app is closed and reopen, the method try to use the network to re-download images instead loading it from cache images.

Next, as larme'spoint, I'd like to dig into `AFNetworking` code to find out what URL path is actually used for their default cache image. Alternatively, I could write an in-disk image cache to not use `AFNetworking` image cache.

Comment: Thanks, so I assume `on-disk cache` would take care cached images when the app is closed. Consider I have tried it on my iPhone or simulator, and be sure the  space is enough. Then I will change the question title to the original one, focus on why cached image is not used when reopen the app.

Comment: See the green counters “Related” on the right side of the stackoverflow webpage? Each represents similar questions.. one of them has your answer i think [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705709/how-to-use-nsurlcache-to-return-cached-api-responses-when-offline-ios-app?rq=1).

Comment: Thank you, I read the whole issue thread in Github. It seems there was an error about `NSURLConnection` in iOS 6 and was fixed in iOS 7, though I meet the same issue again in 2021. I would try to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on line 97 https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/77ef5fed64d98107acd177a90182163a20ba4567/UIKit%2BAFNetworking/UIImageView%2BAFNetworking.m#L97 checking the value of `[imageCache imageforRequest:urlRequest withAdditionalIdentifier:nil]` Indeed `response` nil means using the cache, but their cache, not yours, which I guess is the defaultone as said there https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/77ef5fed64d98107acd177a90182163a20ba4567/UIKit%2BAFNetworking/AFImageDownloader.m

Comment: @Larme, thanks, I did a few test and update in my question, feel free to have a look.

Comment: `I'd like to dig into AFNetworking code to find out what URL path is actually used for their default cache image`: Did you read the code in that method? It's calling `id <AFImageRequestCache> imageCache = downloader.imageCache;`, check the value of that cache, where it's set. And I guess it will be `+ (NSURLCache *)defaultURLCache` unless you set it, or it's a `[[AFAutoPurgingImageCache alloc] init]`... Add breakpoint inside the AFNetworking code...